# Layout inflater error when loading app

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I have a Galaxy Samsung tab 10.1" Model GT-P7510 OS Version 3.2. I tried to load app on it and it's giving me Layout inflater error. Why is this? Here is what logcat says:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
at com.businessplan.BusinessPlannerActivity.onCreate(BusinessPlannerActivity.java:64)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020022 a=-1 r=0x7f020022}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1890)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2462)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:365)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:156)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:152)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed Gen folder and then again clean and build project and the error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an error in the layout file called here:

`android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786) at     com.businessplan.BusinessPlannerActivity.onCreate(BusinessPlannerActivity.java:64) at`

Please check it yourself, or post it here.

Comment: But it's working correctly on other devices. I Have tried it on Motorola xoom and it's working fine. This problem only occurs in Samsung Galaxy 10.1" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Same, error went away after a clean project and do a rebuild.